# How to lazy load without calling my business object layer from my object

Tags: c#, oop, lazy-loading

Simple question
I have a class say person who has as a property a member of another class say Department.
In code terms:

```
class person {
public string fname {get; set;}
public string lname {get; set;}
public Department d {get; set;}
}
```

When I load a person I have my front end web site call my business object layer which then makes a call to my data acess layer, something to this effect:

```
website:
Person p;
p = BOL.GetPerson(1); //call function that returns a person
```

And in my business object layer I simply do some business logic and call the data access layer like so:

BOL:

```
return DAL.GetPerson(1); //returns a person from my Data access layer
```

Inside my DAL i'm simply calling a stored procedure which pulls this information from a person's table.  The only thing is I dont pull the department data because its a rather large structure...

So my question is how can i lazy load this department object in my get property WITHOUT my object knowing or calling the Business Object layer.  In addition, i think it is bad practice to tightly couple a `Department` object with the `BOL` object.

In other words I DONT want to do this in my person class:

```
public Department d {
  get 
     {
      if(d==null)
           {
            d = BOL.GetDepartmentInfo();
           }
     }
  set 
       {
        //some code
        }
```

That is a `person` class should only contain relevant information about a person, so it really should not know about the Business object layer.

How can I solve this problem?

### Edit

Here is the property:

```
public FunctionalGroup Department
{
    get
    {
        if (Department == null)
        {
            Department = GetDepartment();
        }
    }
    set
    {
        Department = value;
    }
}

public Action<FunctionalGroup> GetDepartment { private get; set; }
```

This complains that `Delegate Action does not take 0 arguments`

I tried calling it from the BOL like so:

```
//assume already have an employee object
 e.GetDepartment = (id) => BOL.GetFunctionalGroup(e.FunctionalGroupID);
```

## Edit 2nd time

Basically here is what I have:

```
 private FunctionalGroup _d = null;

        public FunctionalGroup Department
        {
            get
            {
                if (_d == null)
                {
                    _d = GetDepartment();
                }
                return _d;
            }
            set
            {
                _d = value;
            }
        }

//        public Action<string, FunctionalGroup> GetDepartment { private get; set; }

        public Func<FunctionalGroup> GetDepartment { private get; set; }
```

My BOL class is trying to assign to this:

`e.Department = (id) => BOL.GetFunctionalGroup(e.FunctionalGroupID);`

My BOL class says:

```
public static FunctionalGroup GetFunctionalGroup(string fgID)
 {
  return DAL.GetFunctionalGroup(fgID);
 }
```

My DAL looks like this:

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Returns a functional group object along with all of its properties, otherwise null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fgID">String representation of a functional group (ex: "A-AD-C")</param>
        /// <returns>Functional group object with all associated properties, otherwise null.</returns>
        public static FunctionalGroup GetFunctionalGroup(string fgID)
        {
            FunctionalGroup fg = null;

            if (fgID.Length != 0)
            {
                  //connString = the string of our database app found in the resource file
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EMPDLL_selFunctionalGroupByFunctionalGroupID", con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FunctionalGroupID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fgID;
                        con.Open();

                        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                if (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    //found a func group
                                    fg = new FunctionalGroup((string)reader["FunctionalGroupID"],
                                                             (long)reader["ClientID"],
                                                             (string)reader["CostCenter"],
                                                             (string)reader["Description"],
                                                             (string)reader["Comments"],
                                                             (string)reader["AddedBy"],
                                                              reader["DateAdded"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (DateTime?)reader["DateAdded"],
                                                             (string)reader["ModifiedBy"],
                                                             reader["DateModified"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (DateTime?)reader["DateModified"],
                                                             (bool)reader["Inactive"]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return fg;
        }
```

### Final Edit

Ended up using my BOl with this:

`e.GetDepartment = () => BOL.GetFunctionalGroup(e.FunctionalGroupID);`

And my employee class with this:

```
 private FunctionalGroup _d = null;

        public FunctionalGroup Department
        {
            get
            {
                if (_d == null)
                {
                    _d = GetDepartment();
                }
                return _d;
            }
            set
            {
                _d = value;
            }
        }

        public Func<FunctionalGroup> GetDepartment { private get; set; }
```

Comment: I realized my mistake and guffa gets credit: code was changed per the edit above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the person object a callback method that can load the department for that person:

```
class person {

  private Department _department = null;

  public Func<Department> GetDepartment { private get; set; }

  public string fname { get; set; }
  public string lname { get; set; }

  public Department d {
    get {
      if (_department == null) {
        _department = GetDepartment();
      }
      return _department;
    }
  }

}
```

When you get the person object in the business layer:

```
p.GetDepartment = () => BOL.GetDepartment(1);
```

Comment: Could also utilize the `Lazy<T>` type to handle the lazy initialization too.  Would work perfectly with the delegate.

Comment: @Guffa - I guess I am not understanding this...let us assume I created a person object, and as of right now the department object is null.  In the property you said `_department = GetDepartment();` where would GetDepartment be defined?  If you say in the person class, well then this doesnt solve the problem because then this method would have to call the business object layer...

Comment: Ok after re-reading it, it makes sense, I see that it becomes sort of a delegate type and will call the BOL when it needs to.  Very nice solution +1.

Comment: @Guffa - One question is it possible to pass a parameter to `GetDepartment`?

Comment: Here is the code I tried: `e.GetDepartment = () => BOL.GetFunctionalGroup((string)reader["FunctionalGroupID"]);` and the error is Error 1 Delegate 'System.Action<Employees.Objects.FunctionalGroup>' does not take 0 arguments

Comment: @oJM86o: My bad. The delegate should of course be `Func<Department>` to return a value. You would have to store the id from the reader in the person object or in a local variable so that it's included in the delegate closure, as the reader will be gone when you want to read the department. If you want to pass the id into the delegate the type would be `Func<int, Department>`, and you set it using `e.GetDepartment = (id) => BOL.GetFunctionalGroup(id);`.

Comment: @Guffa - can you edit your answer so I can understand this some more.  Basically I just need to pass a string ID to it and expect it to return the information for a department.

Comment: `e.GetDepartment = (e.FunctionalGroupID) => BOL.GetFunctionalGroup(e.FunctionalGroupID);` this throws an error about invalid expression `=>`

Comment: @oJM86o: The parameter in the lambda expression is an identifier, you should not try to put an actual value there. Use `(id) => BOL.GetFunctionalGroup(id)` and call it using `GetDepartment(FunctionalGroupID)`.

Comment: I guess im confused on all of this now :).  I tried this `e.GetDepartment = (id) => DAL.GetFunctionalGroup(id);` and it says `cannot convert employees.objects.functionalgroup to string`  Do youy have time to chat?

Comment: @Guffa - should it be this: `e.GetDepartment = (id) => GetFunctionalGroup(e.FunctionalGroupID);`

Comment: @Guffa see my edited question at the top.  I am still having issues :(

Comment: @oJM86o: No, it should be either `e.GetDepartment = (id) => GetFunctionalGroup(id);` or `e.GetDepartment = () => GetFunctionalGroup(e.FunctionalGroupID);` depending on whether you want to use `Func<int, Department>` and call it using `GetDepartment(e.FUnctionalGroupId)`, or if you want to use `Func<Department>` and call it using `GetDepartment()`. The code in your edited question will cause a stack overflow, as the property getter calls itself. You need a private variable to store the department object in.

Comment: @Guffa is there any way we can chat I tried everything I can think of.  I have this: `public FunctionalGroup Department
        {
            get
            {
                if (_d == null)
                {
                    _d = GetDepartment(FunctionalGroupID);
                }
            }
            set
            {
                _d = value;
            }
        }

        public Action<string, FunctionalGroup> GetDepartment { private get; set; }` and it says Delegate Action does not take 1 arguments.

Comment: @oJM86o: Use `Func` instead of `Action`.

Comment: Basically I am trying to say this: `e.Department = (id) => BOL.GetFunctionalGroup(e.FunctionalGroupID);` and inside my BOL class I have a simple call to my DAL class that says `return DAL.GetFunctionalGroup(e.FunctionalGroupID);` and my dal signature is like so `public static FunctionalGroup GetFunctionalGroup(string fgID)`

Comment: @Guffa see my 2nd edit in my original question hopefulyl this helps explain it ?

Comment: @Guffa even if you want to edit my original question (towards the bottom) and show me how this should be done I am totally ok with that.  Besides its easier and there is more room for code in the question header rather then the comments.  Thanks for taking the time to show me the way :).

Comment: @oJM86o: You are trying to assign a delegate to the `Department` property, which will naturally fail. You should assign it to the `GetDepartment` property, which the `Department` getter will then use for the lazy loading. You won't need a `Department` setter at all for this.

Comment: @Guffa - I guess I dont understand how that will look syntax wise.  Is it possible you can show me syntax wise by editing my answer ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4330/discussion-between-ojm86o-and-guffa)

Comment: @Guffa it wont allow me to give bounty until tomorrow, so Ill give you the credit tomorrow.  Thanks boss!